# With Axios.Get, You have provided an out-of-range value `value` for the select component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, axios, react-hooks

I have been experimenting with ways to initialize a starting value when I get a list of objects to store as menu items. However, I keep getting this error message:

```
You have provided an out-of-range value `bulbasaur` for the select component.
Consider providing a value that matches one of the available options or ''.
The available values are "".
```

I have tried applying `pokemon: "bulbasaur" || ""` since the initial value doesn't propagate in time before it is called. `defaultValue={intitialPokemon.pokemon}` does not seem to work either. How do I pass "Bulbasaur" as the initial value when the value is being pulled from the database afterward?

Here is the full code. You can also access it directly here: https://codesandbox.io/s/pokemon-test-hklo3?file=/src/App.js

```
const intitialPokemon = {
  pokemon: "bulbasaur" || ""
};

export default function App() {
  const [result, setResult] = useState([]);
  const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState(intitialPokemon.pokemon);
  const [data, setData] = useState("");
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const baseURL = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-form/";

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(baseURL, {})
      .then((response) => {
        // console.log("Response: ", response.data.results);
        setResult(response.data.results);
        return response;
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error: ", error);
        return error;
      });
  }, []);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    console.log("Pokemon: ", event.target.value);
    setPokemon(event.target.value);
    let selectedPokemon = result.find(
      (pokemon) => pokemon.name === event.target.value
    );
    console.log("Selected Pokemon: ", selectedPokemon);

    axios
      .get(selectedPokemon.url, {})
      .then((response) => {
        setData(response.request.response);
        console.log(" sds ", response.request.response);
        return response;
      })
      // .get()
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error: ", error);
        return error;
      });
  };

  console.log("Pokemon List: ", result);

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  console.log("Data: ", data);

  return (
    <>
      <FormControl className="dropDown">
        <InputLabel id="demo-controlled-open-select-label">Pokemon</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-controlled-open-select-label"
          id="demo-controlled-open-select"
          open={open}
          defaultValue={intitialPokemon.pokemon}
          onClose={handleClose}
          onOpen={handleOpen}
          value={pokemon}
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          {result.map((item) => (
            <MenuItem key={item.name} value={item.name} url={item.url}>
              {item.name}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
      <div className="App">{data}</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're setting select's default value before `axios` get data. You can set the default option of select manually and filter the result for preventing `MenuItem` showing duplicate value:

```
<Select
          labelId="demo-controlled-open-select-label"
          id="demo-controlled-open-select"
          open={open}
          defaultValue={intitialPokemon.pokemon}
          onClose={handleClose}
          onOpen={handleOpen}
          value={pokemon}
          onChange={handleChange}>
          <MenuItem value={intitialPokemon.pokemon}>
            bulbasaur
          </MenuItem>
          {result
            .filter((x) => x.name != intitialPokemon.pokemon)
            .map((item) => (
              <MenuItem key={item.name} value={item.name}>
                {item.name}
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
</Select>
```

[image: Edit Pokemon Test (forked)]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to use a blank initial value then set the Pokemon to the first Pokemon name received. To do this, I moved the code inside `handleChange()` into its own method, `requestPokemon()`. When your initial request is finished inside `useEffect`, it calls that same `requestPokemon()` method using "bulbasaur".

```
export default function App() {
  const [result, setResult] = useState([]);
  const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState("");
  const [data, setData] = useState("");
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const baseURL = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-form/";

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(baseURL, {})
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("Response: ", response.data.results[0].name);
        setResult(response.data.results);
        //Show Bulbasaur. This assumes "bulbasaur" exists in the response.
        requestPokemon(response.data.results[0].name);
        return response;
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error: ", error);
        return error;
      });
  }, []);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    requestPokemon(event.target.value);
  };

  const requestPokemon = (name) => {
    //You should run a conditional here so that the request is not made if the value is still blank
    console.log("Pokemon: ", name);
    setPokemon(name);
    let selectedPokemon = result.find((pokemon) => pokemon.name === name);
    console.log("Selected Pokemon: ", selectedPokemon);

    axios
      .get(selectedPokemon.url, {})
      .then((response) => {
        setData(response.request.response);
        console.log(" sds ", response.request.response);
        return response;
      })
      // .get()
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error: ", error);
        return error;
      });
  };
}
```